# MATLAB Generate Conditional Matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am new to MATLAB and having difficulties on an assignment.

I want to create a m*n binary matrix where;

- Max 1 element in a row must be 1
- Exactly 1 element in a column must be 1
- There must be exactly n elements which are 1

### I have to find all possible solutions.

**Example 4*3 matrix**

```matlab
[
 1, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 1;
 0, 1, 0
];
```

Comment: Picking _n_ different rows from _m_ columns turns out to just be a k-combinations problem in disguise - are you stuck on generating the combinations, or turning them into matrices?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you allowed to use built-in MATLAB functions, or do you need to code the solution yourself?

Comment: I tried to solve the problem by generating numbers, such as 11, 12, 21, 22 etc, all pointing to an index in array, but nothing works so far.

I can use built-in functions.

I am having difficulty on the solution algorithm, don't know how to solve.